# Azure function: how to extract the value from a key that is also a keyword?

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I have an azure function (webhook) that receives the following JSON.

```
[ 
    { "email": "example@test.com", "event": "processed"} , 
    { "email": "example@test.com", "event": "deferred"} ,
    { "email": "example@test.com", "event": "open"}
]
```

I want to parse the JSON and add the individual items to an azure table.

When I try to read the values of the individual items, I get an error on item.event (I guess because event is a keyword?)

```
string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

foreach (var item in data)
{
    outputTable.Add(
    new EventMsg()
    {
        email = item.email,
        eventType = item.event
    });
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: As a side-note, I don't think this is Azure-specific at all. You'd get the same error in a small console app with hard-coded JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@` in front of a keyword to treat it as an identifier:

```
eventType = item.@event
```

Alternatively, I *suspect* you could use the indexer:

```
eventType = item["event"]
```

... but you'd need to check that.